# AWS Connection refused after upgrade instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a node.js backend on an instance of AWS. I upgraded my instance from micro to medium, and after that, I get 'Connection refused' on my API calls. I change my IP, and I have security groups configurated and selected.

Please help me, I don't know what can I do.

By SSH it's working perfectly.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain this by ssh it's working perfectly do you mean ssh is fine or do you mean by ssh API calls are fine?

Comment: what is the os type?

Comment: Hi, I mean when I connect to my EC2 by SSH it's working fine. OS: Ubuntu.

Comment: I have a docker container running, on port 3000, and when I do netstat -an | grep 3000, that is what I got:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN